# Flowerpot falls off a windowsill

Tags: physics

A flowerpot falls off a windowsill and falls past the window below. You may ignore air resistance. It takes time $0.420sec(s)$ to pass this window, which is of height $1.90meters(m)$. How far is the top of the window below the windowsill from which the flowerpot fell?

So what I have done is the following:

Since the pot is falling downwards, $a=-9.81\frac{m}{s^2}$.

The initial velocity is $v_0=0 \frac{m}{s}$ and the initial position is $x_0=0 m$.

Let the displacement of the x be $\Delta x=(1.90-y)m -0m$, where y is the distance between the top of the lower window and the bottom of the upper window. So, $x_f=(1.90+y)m$

Thus, I use the following formula to compute my answer:

$x_f=x_0 + v_0 t + \frac{1}{2}at^2 $

The goal is to find y.

$(1.90+y)m=(1.90-y)m + 0 \frac{m}{s} (0.420s) + \frac{1}{2} (9.81 \frac{m}{s^2})(0.420s)^2$

$(y)m=(-y)m + \frac{1}{2}(9.81)(0.420)^2m= [-y+\frac{1}{2}(9.81)(0.420)^2]m$

$y=-y+\frac{1}{2}(9.81)(0.420)^2$

$2y=\frac{1}{2}(9.81)(0.420)^2$

$y=\frac{1}{4}(9.81)(0.420)^2=1.03005$

Is my work correct because according to masteringphysics it isnt?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume upwards is positive. We have two equations:

$$\begin{align}
-y =& \frac{1}{2}(-9.81)t^2\\
-(y+1.90) =& \frac{1}{2}(-9.81)(t+.420)^2
\end{align}$$

where $t$ is the time until the flowerpot reaches the top of the lower window. You should be able to find out this $t$ and then get $y$.

Comment: When I use your formulas I get t=-0.67 and y=-2.2. This seems totally wrong are you sure about your equations?

Comment: Edited :)${}{}{}{}$